# Android Studio - Ruined seekbar

Tags: android, xml, seekbar

I have a problem with my seekBar. When I am implementing to Android Studio, seebars look good and works perfectly.

Here is a photo.

[View in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvoIr.png)

When I run app in real device seekBars is ruined out, but I do not know why ?

Here is a photo of problem.

[View in app on real device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q8sg.png)

Any idea ? of course here is a code ...

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/seekBarIsVisibleFps"
                android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressline"
                android:max="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:progress="1"/>
                ... ... ...
```

Here is a code from thumb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <solid android:color="#c60026" />
   <size
    android:width="16dp"
    android:height="16dp" />
</shape>
```

... and here is a progressline

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="12dp"
                android:color="#878787" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:width="12dp"
                    android:color="#5e5e5e" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Post your thumb and progress drawables.

Comment: http://qtcstation.com/2011/05/android-how-to-fix-seekbar-bar-thumb-centering-issues/http://qtcstation.com/2011/05/android-how-to-fix-seekbar-bar-thumb-centering-issues/